# Limit points in interior of other set?

Tags: general-topology

Given a normal topological space $ X $, and given two disjoint open sets $ A, B $ in it, is possible that exist limit points of $ A$ in the interior points of $ B $?

Comment: Are there any requirements on $A$ and $B$? Must they be disjoint?

Comment: Yes, sorry, they're disjoint.

Comment: What is a normal set?

Comment: The way we understood a normal set is a set which is Hausdorff and for each pair of closed subsets $A,B\subseteq X$, there exist open subsets $M,N$ where $A\subseteq M$, $B\subseteq N$ and $M\cap N=\emptyset$.

Comment: Perhaps the question will be more understandable by replacing "normal set" with "normal topological space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Suppose $x$ is in the interior of $B$. Then, there is an open set $U\ni x$, such that $U\subseteq B$. Since $B\cap A=\emptyset$, it follows that $U\cap A=\emptyset$. Thus, $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ that misses $A$. Thus, $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.